# SQL Server AFTER INSERT trigger not working, how does trigger work?

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2019

I wrote a trigger after insert on a table, the number 5 in a specific column on the table, but after I do an insert, nothing happens. I'm wondering what mistakes I have in my code so that after an insert nothing happens

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_EstadoDoc]
ON [dbo].[EstadoDoc]
AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Puntaje1 INT; 
    DECLARE @Puntaje2 INT;

    SET @Puntaje1 = (SELECT 5 
                     FROM EstadoDoc, inserted
                     WHERE inserted.IdDoc = EstadoDoc.IdDoc 
                       AND inserted.Estado IN ('A','RyR') 
                       AND EstadoDoc.Estado = 'S')

    SET @Puntaje2 = (SELECT 10 
                     FROM EstadoDoc, inserted
                     WHERE inserted.IdDoc = EstadoDoc.IdDoc 
                       AND inserted.Estado IN ('A') 
                       AND EstadoDoc.Estado = 'RyR')

    IF @Puntaje1 != NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE EstadoDoc
        SET PuntajePrevio = @puntaje1 
        FROM EstadoDoc, inserted
        WHERE inserted.IdDoc = EstadoDoc.IdDoc 
          AND inserted.Secuencia = EstadoDoc.Secuencia
    END

    IF @Puntaje2 != NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE EstadoDoc
        SET PuntajePrevio = @puntaje2 
        FROM EstadoDoc, inserted
        WHERE inserted.IdDoc = EstadoDoc.IdDoc 
          AND inserted.Secuencia = EstadoDoc.Secuencia
    END
```

Comment: When do you actualy create the trigger? If i look at these examples: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/after-insert-triggers-in-sql-server/ There is a CREATE TRIGGER but i do not see it with yours.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: And to nag about a third major problem: you **cannot** use the regular `!=` inequality operator to compare with `NULL` - only `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` will work properly

Comment: See this [all too common issue](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See all my comments - you basically need to rewrite your trigger to use a proper **set-based** approach to handle multi-row inserts, and you need to get in the habit of using proper ANSI/ISO **JOIN** syntax (instead of the deprecated comma-separated table list in the `FROM` clause).

Try something like this - the trigger also looks a lot simpler that way!

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_EstadoDoc]
ON [dbo].[EstadoDoc]
AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- as per charlieface's recommendation - check to see if any rows 
    -- have actually been inserted at all - if not, bow out
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted))
         RETURN;

    UPDATE e
    SET PuntajePrevio = 5
    FROM dbo.EstadoDoc e
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.IdDoc = e.IdDoc 
                          AND i.Secuencia = e.Secuencia
    WHERE e.Estado = 'S'
      AND i.Estado IN ('A', 'RyR');
      
    UPDATE e
    SET PuntajePrevio = 10
    FROM dbo.EstadoDoc e
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.IdDoc = e.IdDoc 
                          AND i.Secuencia = e.Secuencia
    WHERE i.Estado = 'A'
      AND e.Estado = 'RyR';
END
```

Comment: You could combine the two `update`s like this `WHERE e.Estado = 'S' AND i.Estado IN ('A', 'RyR') OR i.Estado = 'A' AND e.Estado = 'RyR'` and a `CASE` for the `SET` value. Also `SET NOCOUNT ON;` would be wise, as well as an zero-row early bailout `IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted)) RETURN;`

Comment: @Charlieface: added the `SET NOCOUNT ON` - thanks! But why that "zero-row bailout"? I was under the impression, if no INSERT happens, the trigger doesn't get fired - or the other way around: if the trigger fires, there will always be at least one row in `Inserted` - no?

Comment: No absolutely not true https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f314b72362855af96e198c9562a5ea5a therefore for perf reasons it's best to do an early bailout, eg on our database it prevents 4 levels of triggers firing

Comment: @Charlieface: interesting - so the `AFTER INSERT` trigger gets actually fired - even though **no rows** were really inserted...... hmmm......

Comment: The key thing to remember about triggers in SQL Server, is that they run *per statement*, as you indicate, so it's perfectly logical that it runs on a zero-row insert, you may for example want to log that an `insert` statement has been run, even if there are no rows. Note that `@@ROWCOUNT` is unreliable in triggers, due to `merge` giving incorrect results, plus it would have had to be the very first statement.